# How to remove string after fixed character

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this

`str[0] = "99.1234567"`
I wnat to remove all charcter after 3 decimal.

Means

`str[0] = "99.123"`

How to remove this after three decimal. Also sometime i will get only two decimal point like`11.36` in that case i wnat to be ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just find the index of the period, and use `substr` to get the portion of the string you want.

```
str[0].substr(0, str[0].indexOf(".")+4);
```

it's OK if the string is shorter than the length specified in `substr`.

Comment: keep in mind that this might mess up your result without warning if your input string contains more than one period!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using [Number.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) , but first you need ot convert the string to number :

```js
var str = "99.1234567"

console.log(Number(str).toFixed(3))
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it :

```
parseFloat("99.1234567").toFixed(3) // "99.123"
```

Comment: keep in mind that in the case of "99.9999", this will round up, resulting in "100.000"

Comment: Will it?? Damn Javascript

Comment: yep ;) it's sneaky like that.

Answer (score 2):

If string :

```
str[0] = "99.1234567";
parseFloat(str[0]).toFixed(3); 
console.log(str[0]); //"99.123"

          Or 

Math.round(str[0] * 1000)/1000;
```